# Unit тестирование методов, которые напрямую обращаются к базе

Tags: c#, sql-server, юнит-тесты

Допустим, есть служебный класс, где сконцентрирована работа с БД.

Т.е там прямые запросы к БД.

Я правильно понимаю, что `SqlConnection` я ничем не смогу заменить, что бы отлучить тестирование от БД?

=> получается, что в Unit-тестах я должен делать проверочные запросы?

Comment: Наверное, корректность выполнения запросов при разных параметрах, которые передаются в методы.

Comment: @Kromster, не знаю. Может МОК объекты шагнули далеко вперед=D

Comment: @Kromster Ок, с бд понятно. А можно по потробнее про тестирование конструктора запросов?

Comment: Юнит тестирование предполагает тестирование какого-то маленького кусочка логики. Тестирование запросов это уже интеграционное тестирование. Ну и вообще не понятно, для чего тестировать запросы к бд

Comment: для EF есть вот [такая штука](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

Answer (score 4):

А как можно проверить корректность *выполнения* запросов, не *выполняя* их на БД?

Смотря что вы проверяете. Если непосредственно запросы - то можете их потестировать только на другой "голой"/специальной тестовой БД, например. Если тестируете конструктор запросов, то тут есть варианты.

Если у вас есть конструктор запросов, то вы можете попробовать потестировать его работу и получающиеся запросы без БД (лишние запятые, наличие всех необходимых секций, дублирование полей, алиасов и т.п.), но наличие БД конечно дело бы упростило, т.к. в итоге только БД является финальной инстанцией которая выполнит запрос и скажет валиден он или нет.

---

И в комментариях верно придираются, юнит-тестирование - это тестирование юнитов, изолированных кусочков логики, а тестирование связи разных систем - это интеграционное тестирование.